# Does Ext.data.Store only used for model collections?

Tags: extjs

I see in the document page: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.data.Store.html

> The Store class encapsulates a client side cache of Ext.data.Model objects. Stores load data via a Ext.data.proxy.Proxy, and also provide functions for sorting, filtering and querying the Ext.data.Model instances contained within it

Seems like it should always be an array of Model.

My question is how to handle the case that I want only one object not an array, like a user object which id=111. Should the backend return just a user object, e.g. `{"username": "Jeff"}`, or an array contains only one object `[{"username": "Jeff"}`?

I'm quite new to ExtJs, and these questions really confused me. Thanks!

Comment: I see the question is closed but ExtJS provides a way to load a single model instead of a store. This works well with typical REST APIs which usually have different response for getting one piece of data or a list.

Comment: Like `GET /books` can return a list of books (ExtJS store containing ExtJS models) and `GET /books/1` only one book (ExtJS model).

Comment: Use a `Ext.data.model` and define a `proxy` config for it. Use a `Ext.data.model` and define a `proxy` config for it. If used this way the back-end should return an object instead of an array, otherwise you might need to do a bit more to get to the first element of the result.